# SSL Error When Attempting to Install Tinytex on RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, tinytex

I'm attempting to install Tinytex on RStudio so I can download my Rmd as a PDF without issues. I tried to do so without Tinytex and got an invalid PDF error. When I install Tinytex, using install.packages("tinytex")

as specified on the Tinytex website, it's fine. But the next line,

```
tinytex::install_tinytex()
```

only yields the following error:

```
172.67.140.24, 104.21.87.33, 2606:4700:3035::6815:5721, ...
Connecting to yihui.org (yihui.org)|172.67.140.24|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
TinyTeX was not successfully installed or configured. tlmgr was found at /usr/bin/tlmgr. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/faq/ for more information.

Error in download.file(url, output, ..., method = method) : 'wget' call had nonzero exit status
```

I have already tried mutliple configurations of install(), but versions such as:

```
tinytex::install_tinytex(repository = "http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/CTAN/", version = "latest") 

does not recognize the version "latest":
unused argument (version = "latest")
```

or any other version I try.

Removing the version does not help, and yields similar errors.

I have also tried several mirrors, such as
'http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/',
but those all return the same error I initially encountered.

I have tried restarting RStudio, and using a VPN (as some online boards suggested errors in connecting to the internet), but nothing seems to help.

This is for a first assignment in an R Coursera Course, and the actual RMarkdown is very, very simple. I am only just starting in R with some experience in Python. Both R and RStudio are the latest versions, I just donwloaded them today.

Any help would be appreciated.